# hive extract keys from a dict like string by regexp_extract?

Tags: regex, hive

I want to extract keys from a column from a hive table that likes this below

```
{"agya":3,"gentong":1,"tronton":0,"tasikmalaya":4,"tanja":2}
{"afifah":3,"sctv":10,"samuel zylgwyn":2,"naysila mirdad":0,"shared":8}
{"aferia":1,"jatimtimes":3,"apbdes":2,"siltap":4,"mudjito":0}
{"aerox":0,"flasher":1,"lampu hazard":2,"aftermarket":4,"dcs":5}
{"administratif":6,"fakta":7,"prabowo":5,"cek":4,"admistratif":0}
{"adeg":2,"tiru":1,"film film":3,"romantis":0,"nggak":5}
```

for the first one I want to get `"agya", "gentong", "tronton"` etc. And later I can explode them to multiple rows.
How to use regexp_extract to realize this ?

Comment: what's the datatype of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regexp_extract()` returns string. To get an array, use `split()` function, it also uses regexp as a delimiter pattern. So, you can split by `':\\d+,'`

```
split(
     regexp_replace(col, '^\\{|\\}$',''), --remove outer curly braces {}
     ':\\d+,' --array elements delimiter pattern
     ) --this will give array "agya", "gentong", etc
```

After exploding the array you can remove quotes using `regexp_replace(col_exploded,'\\"','')`

**Update**

Last key:value does not contain `,`, so need to fix the template and use `,|$` (comma or end of the string).
Also last element will be empty, need to filter it out.

**Test:**

```
hive> select regexp_replace(key,'\\"','') key
    > from
    > (
    > select explode(
    > split(
    >      regexp_replace('{"agya":3,"gentong":1,"tronton":0,"tasikmalaya":4,"tanja":2}', '^\\{|\\}$',''), --remove outer curly braces {}
    >      ':\\d+(,|$)' --array elements delimiter pattern
    >      )
    > ) as key
    > )s
    > where key!=''
    > ;
OK
agya
gentong
tronton
tasikmalaya
tanja
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below solution :

```
select map_keys(str_to_map(regexp_replace(mycol,'[{}"]','')));
```

Here,

```
1.regexp_replace function is used to replace all the '{','}','"' characters with nothing.
2.str_to_map function has beeen used to convert the string to map.
3.map_keys function is used to extract the keys from the map which will give the result in an array format.
4.You can then explode this array as per your need.
```

Thanks